# Inserting Text parts block wise into array perl

Tags: arrays, perl, text

my problem is, that i want to break down the file and insert the pieces into an array.

Starting from NONVSAM (the whole line) to PC File (the whole line).

So that in $array[0] I have the first block saved and in $array[n] the last block.

I have a file like this:

---

NONVSAM  - XXXPROD.YYY.XLIST

Y A DynP LSEQ     0     0           00000000 00000000 20150807 87654321

PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/

NONVSAM  - XXXPROD.ZZZ.XYZZZ

Y A DynP LSEQ     0     0           00000000 00000000 20150807 12345678

PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/
...

...

...

Comment: Did you try somthing, what is not working?

Comment: i tried to grep -C 1, but in some blocks there are additional lines so that didn't word. split on blank didn't work either because the number of blank differ.

Comment: Is every alternate line really blank like that? Is there ever anything between a closing `PC File` line and an opening `NONVSAM` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `PC File` lines always follow the `NONVSAM` lines, then this is very easily done by simply starting a new array element every time `NONVSAM` appears

This program expects the path to the input file on the command line, like so

```
$ main.pl data.txt
```

Note that I have used `Data::Dump` only to reveal the final contents of the `@data` array

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data;

while ( <> ) {
    push @data, '' if /^NONVSAM/;
    $data[-1] .= $_;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;
```

#### output

```
[
  "NONVSAM - XXXPROD.YYY.XLIST\nY A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 87654321\nPC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/\n",
  "NONVSAM - XXXPROD.ZZZ.XYZZZ\nY A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 12345678\nPC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/\n",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr;
my @tmp;
while(<DATA>) {         # read the file one line at a time
    chomp;              # remove the linebreak
    push @tmp, $_;      # store the line in a temporary array
    if (/^PC File/) {   # if the line begins with PC File
        push @arr, join"\n",@tmp;   # Sat=ve all the line in the result array
        @tmp = ();      # re-init the temp array
    }
}
say Dumper\@arr;

__DATA__
NONVSAM - XXXPROD.YYY.XLIST
Y A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 87654321
PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/
NONVSAM - XXXPROD.ZZZ.XYZZZ
Y A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 12345678
PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/ ...
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'NONVSAM - XXXPROD.YYY.XLIST
Y A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 87654321
PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/',
          'NONVSAM - XXXPROD.ZZZ.XYZZZ
Y A DynP LSEQ 0 0 00000000 00000000 20150807 12345678
PC File - /shared/xx/dir/dir2/xxx/ ...'
        ];
```

Comment: I get the error that i can't use Modern::Perl, also could u tell me how u read the file direct into the script? I tried it with:  my $file = "/shared/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt";  open (FILE, "<", $file); close (<FILE>); and use <FILE> in the While loop

Comment: @crossing: If you can't install `Modern::Perl`, remove it from the script and change `say` with `print`. In your attempt to read the file, remove the `close FILE` or put it after the `while(<FILE>)`

Comment: thank you!!!!! worked perfectly!